# smooth scrolling in pure css parallax

Tags: ios, css, parallax

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/11ec63xj/1/

Try to open above demo in iphone, the scrolling is not smooth at all. Later I learned to use

```
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

but it broke my parallax effect.

Answer (score -2):

Try adding

```
overflow-y: scroll;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

to the .parallax div

http://jsfiddle.net/11ec63xj/4/

That should do it :)